# Using HTML/CSS to customize Chart.js chart title

Tags: html, css, chart.js

I would like to customize a Chart.js chart title using / injecting HTML & CSS. From the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html), it seems pretty clear you can do just that, but but the docs do not give an example of how this is done:
[image]

I have tried using an inline `<span>` tag to color one specific word in the title, leaving the other words the default font color. But this approach does not work, as it renders the title with the markup itself instead of styling the word "blue" with a blue font color. Note that all the CSS (including the styling I want to apply in the chart title) is inside a `<style>` tag in the `<head>`.

Here is a fully working example using starter code from the (un?)official [Chart.js YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/@ChartJS-tutorials).

I am using Chart.js v4.4.1. Can anyone provide a working example of how you can use HTML / CSS to further customize the chart title?

```js
const data = {
  labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Weekly Sales",
    data: [18, 12, 6, 9, 12, 3, 9],
    backgroundColor: [
      "rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)",
      "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
      "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
      "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
      "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
      "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
      "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
    ],
    borderColor: [
      "rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)",
      "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
      "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
      "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
      "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
      "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
      "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
    ],
    borderWidth: 1,
  }, ],
};

// config
const config = {
  type: "bar",
  data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false, // don't show the box above the chart
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        // THIS IS WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO CUSTOMIZE
        text: "This is a <span class='blue-word'>blue</span> word",
        font: {
          weight: 200,
          size: 22,
        },
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          font: {
            size: 18,
          },
        },
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        ticks: {
          font: {
            size: 18,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

// render init block
const myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), config);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.chartMenu {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 60px;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  color: rgba(54, 162, 235, 1);
}

.chartMenu p {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.chartCard {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  background: rgba(4, 150, 248, 0.776);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.chartBox {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: solid 3px rgba(54, 162, 235, 1);
  background: white;
}

.blue-word {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="chartCard">
  <div class="chartBox">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.1/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not sure if _"you can implement the title with HTML and CSS"_ actually means you can do it via the script - or whether that is just suggesting, if you need a fancier title, then implement it yourself, by positioning something _above_ the canvas ...? The `title` as specified above does get rendered _into_ the canvas after all - and I doubt they would have been bothered to implement the functionality to "render" whatever HTML & CSS construct you might pass, _onto_ the canvas.

Comment: The answer is [not out of the box](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html)

Comment: You only have `myChart.options.plugins.title.text` and not `myChart.options.plugins.title.html`

Comment: I take the "Note: you can use HTML and CSS..." to mean that I can make the title in HTML, *outside* the chart.js canvas